# Problems understanding index notation

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm reading *Spacetime and Geometry* and I have problems understanding index notation of matrix multiplication. Why is
$$
\eta=\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda
$$
in index notation 
$$
\eta_{\rho \sigma}=\Lambda^{\mu'}_{\rho}\eta_{\mu'\nu'}\Lambda^{\nu'}_\sigma?$$

Maybe someone can explain how the index notation works in this case (I know it's a very stupid question).

Comment: If an index in a product appears twice, once as upper and once as lower index, it is summed over. That's called Einstein summation convention.

Comment: It is by no means a stupid question. Consider first the simpler cases of multiplication of a matrix by a vector $Y=AX$ which reads $y_i=a_i^k x_k$ or multiplication of 2 matrices $C=AB$ which reads $c_i^j=a_i^k b_k^j.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $(AB)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} B_{kj}$ (defn of matrix multiplication).

Repeated use of that gives -

$\begin{array}{rcl}(\Lambda \eta \Lambda)_{ij}&=&\sum_k(\Lambda\eta)_{ik}\Lambda_{kj}\\
&=&\sum_k\sum_l\Lambda_{il}\eta_{lk}\Lambda_{kj}
\end{array}$

In the Einstein notation, it is customary to use Greek symbols for indices.

Answer (score 0):

The index convention being used, sometimes called the "Einstein summation convention," is that any index that appears twice, once as a contravariant index (a superscript) and once as a covariant index (a subscript) 9is to be summed over from $1$ to for (in the convention that $x = x_1, y=x_2, z=x_3, t = x_4$).

That notation convention in general $d$-dimensional spacetime refers to summation over however many spacetime indices are present.

Caution - if you ever do renormilzation using dimensional regularizatoin (working in $4+\epsilon$ dimensions to control certain infinities that come up in quantum field theory expansions), you have to be careful about which summations of $\delta_a^b$ give $4$ and which give $4+\epsilon$.

Comment: Likely the convention is $x^0=ct$ and $x^i={x,y,z}, i=1,2,3$

Comment: When doing theoretical physics, one ususally works in a system of units where $c=1$.

Comment: Depends on the theory, Sean Carol who writes Spacetime and Geometry uses natural units, I just noted that this is typically the standard and it's best to not forget where c is if not using natural units. In low energy theory this isn't often the case